# How have you set up your database? Do you have to change a lot with a new year?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a question about databases. What does your database actually look like? Suppose you have a table for quotations.

For example, now it is 2021. You have 1000 (id AUTO_INCREMENT) requests at the end of the year, so 1000 rows.

How do you make the quotation numbering available for the year 2022 if they have to start from 0 again? Will you make a whole new table and change the codes everywhere on the website(as I do)? Or do you approach it completely differently?

Comment: Why would you need to start at 0 again? An auto increment field should represent each row uniquely. Therefore there can't be duplicates. If you're creating multiple tables with the same set of columns, just to represent a different year, then you're denormalising your data and making it harder to search it, etc. Just add the year as another column to the quotations table. If you need to number the quotations, and start again at each new year, you could calculate it on the fly in your UI application, or maybe store another column in the table with it. But don't make new tables.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your comment. It's because of the many questions about it. Like, how many quotes do we have in 3 months now? How many quotes do we now have in 6 months? And all year round. Can't you easily answer this if you restart the numbering every year?

Comment: @ADyson What I have indeed done now is a column 'year' where local date time (year) gets inserted in.

Comment: Just store a date along with (but separate to) the quote number

Comment: As strawberry and I said, just store a date in the table along with each row, and then you can answer those kinds of questions with a simple COUNT query, restricting the rows by date. (Simply looking at the latest auto increment number would be inaccurate for that anyway, if you had ever deleted a row)

Comment: @ADyson actually your suggestion was subtly different from mine!

Comment: @Strawberry really, how? I'm clearly having an off day

Comment: @ADyson Or an off *year*???

Comment: @Strawberry lol that must be it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an entry date column and stamp each record as it is created.  Then I would query the table for records that were created within a date window.

Example:

The below code will add a new column to your table.

By default this column will contain the date the record was entered.
(Any existing records will carry the date you run the query for the first time.)

```
ALTER TABLE [yourTable]
ADD [entryDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE())
```

Afterward you can count records between two dates like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [RECORD COUNT]
FROM [yourTable]
WHERE [entryDate] BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2022-01-01'
```

Comment: Maybe I'm out-of-touch, but are you sure that this is valid MySQL syntax?